# importing duplicate contacts from outlook to sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, outlook, contacts

I imported a bunch of outlook contacts to a OOTB sharepoint contacts list.

it however did not copy some contacts with similar names.

Is there a way for me to force copy all contacts to the list??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you see if this works out for you?
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/hr/onlineservicessharepoint/thread/2dad33eb-b120-4961-8f03-6cde4057e81f

and / or check this out:

1. Click on File > Import and Export
2. Choose Export to a file and then next
3. Choose Comma (or Tab) separated values (Windows) and then next
4. Navigate to Contacts in the list of folders and then next
5. Provide a filename and location to save the contacts list and then Next
6. To customize the fields to export, choose Map Custom Fields
7. Modify the fields that you wish to export
8. Click OK and then Finish to export the file.
9. Open the file in Excel and then save it as an excel document (XLS or XLSX)
10. Go to SharePoint and choose to create a new list.
11. Select Import from Excel under Custom Lists
12. Import your contacts list.

taken from https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/endusersharepointcom-how-do-i-import-contacts-from-outlook-2003-to-wss.aspx

hope this helps :)